# How to let vim do syntax highlight right for flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

***Some background:*** I am using VSCode for coding in flutter. But when I open many workspaces, it ate all my free RAM quickly (Macbookpro 8GB). *(IntelliJ is even worse.)* Sometimes, I just need to check other workspaces' Code etc.. So The best option is to use vim for this purpose.

I have installed `dart-vim-plugin`, but the syntax highlighting is not really correct for flutter, for example, `BuildContext`, `Scaffold`, `AppBar` etc.. all the class types are pure white color. To minimize the RAM usage, I just don't want any analysis server, auto completion etc.. I just want the editor has a correct syntax highlighting so that I can easily check the code. Is that doable?

Thank you very much for your help.

PS: I just want to use an editor which only does syntax highlight. I really don't have much free RAM. Normally, there are only 600MB left and I don't want to use them all.

Comment: try https://dart-atom.github.io/dart/, here you have a screenshot: https://github.com/dart-atom/dart

Comment: @pskink thanks for the comment. But that is too much for a simple editor. It just looks like another VSCode or IntelliJ. All I want is just syntax highlight and nothing else.

Comment: check https://blog.atom.io/2018/01/10/the-state-of-atoms-performance.html and see the image at the bottom (red chart) - it shows the memory usage of 600M - you have 12 times more

Comment: @pskink sorry, not really. even if I have 8GB RAM physically, but when I open all the development tools including browsers. I only have 600MB free RAM in MacOS. I just don't want anything except syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if I am new to vim syntax highlight, since nobody provides an answer, I have to study how to do this by myself. I have created my own [dart.vim](https://gist.github.com/sgon00/3e6636f7cafcecb7ed88df9169d8229c) and put it at `~/.vim/after/syntax/dart.vim`. Note this is just an add-on for `dart-vim-plugin`, you still need to install  it. Hopefully, this will help somebody some day.

Comment: did you consider to send this as pull-request to `dart-vim-plugin` ?

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this. I really want to use vim with Flutter, but the syntax highlighting (or lack thereof) made it less appealing to me.

You should totally make a PR out of this because dart-vim-plugin doesn't really do any syntax highlighting on Flutter classes.